# Unable to deserialize the the GenericData avro data in Spring cloud streams kstreams

Tags: spring, stream, cloud, avro, apache-kafka-streams

Unable to deserialize the avro GenericData in Spring cloud streams KStreams.

In my producer, I am serializing the data using `KafkaAvroSerializer class`and sending to kafka as GenericData object in avro format. But while deserializing given the following consumer properties.

> key.deserializer:org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer,value.deserializer:
>   io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer

```
input.map(new KeyValueMapper<byte[], GenericData, KeyValue<String, String>>() {   
 @Override
                    public KeyValue<String, String> apply(byte[] s, GenericData genericRecord) {
//                        genericRecord
                        return new KeyValue<String, String>(s, genericRecord.toString());
                    }

  });
```

I would like to get the GenericData object directly in the map method with deserialization. but getting the error. 
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData getting this error.

Comment: I am not familiar with Spring, however, the error indicates that you did not configure the correct `default.value.serde`.